# String to expression does not work properly

Tags: string-manipulation, syntax, expression

Consider the following string:

```
string = "Displacement_0.5_ToDecVol_38_FidLength_50";
```

I would like to extract the three numbers from it: `{0.5,38,50}`. This is an attempt:

```
parameters = 
 StringCases[string, 
   "Displacement_" ~~ displacement : NumberString ~~ "_ToDecVol_" ~~ 
     ToDecVol : NumberString ~~ "_FidLength_" ~~ 
     FidLength : NumberString ~~ _ :> {displacement, ToDecVol, 
     FidLength}][[1]]//ToExpression
```

However, it returns only the first digit from the last number:

> {0.5, 38, 5}

The same situation would happen if setting any other number, say 511, instead of 50: it drops the last digit. Could you please tell me how to fix the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest fix would be to change the final _ to ___. I.e. the pattern would look like this:

```
"Displacement_" ~~ displacement : NumberString ~~ "_ToDecVol_" ~~ 
  ToDecVol : NumberString ~~ "_FidLength_" ~~ 
  FidLength : NumberString ~~ ___
```

But you could just do this:

```
StringCases[string, NumberString] // ToExpression
```